# Woo-commerce product coupons error

Tags: woocommerce

i am using woo-commerce 2.4.2 version. i created a coupon for a product and it is functionality is not correct. The system is giving discounts for all the product in the cart rather than for one particular product.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshot or link or something?

Comment: @VidishPurohit  I am facing problem in attaching the screenshot. i could explain you in detail. i created a product coupon for a particular product which could be used unlimited times. The problem is the system is applying the discount to all the other products in the cart.

Comment: So, I believe that you are using condition - product should be in cart to use this coupon. In that case, discount should be applied to the cart & not product. I don't think there is a coupon option which allows to add coupons for specific product.

Comment: I think you are looking for _"Product Discounts"_ right? If this is the case then you can add the product ID(s) under Products field in Usage restriction tab of Add/Edit Coupon.

Comment: @RaunakGupta  thanks Raunak. even after choosing the product it is not working. coupon is applying for all the products in the cart.

Comment: without knowing your full settings option it's tough to say what not working.

Comment: WooCommerce 2.4.2 was released on August 11, 2015!!  It's almost 2 years old. This question is off-topic because it isn't programming-specific and falls more under the purview of "how do I use" this software, which isn't covered here. However, please update your WooCommerce!

Comment: @ RaunakGupta. Please check the screen shot of the settings.

Comment: @helgatheviking it is not "how do I use". It is an technical issue. the product coupon has some functional issue. Instead of applying for one particular product it is applying for all the products in the cart.

Comment: Maybe, but in any case, for me, it isn't worth debugging a 2 year old piece of software. I still advise updating WooCommerce. It could well be that an updated WooCommerce will solve this issue for you. Do test everything on a sandbox site before going live.

Comment: @helgatheviking. I guess i have to update it first. Thanks